# accessing outer static class using reflection

Tags: c#

I am implementing an Mqtt API, and as far as logical grouping goes i was planning on having

```
static class API {
    static class Topics {
        static string path = "someRootPath";
        static class Commands {
            static string path = outerClass.path + "/commands";
            static class Target1 {
                static string path = outerClass.path + "/target1";
                static class Action1 {
                    static string path = outerClass.path + "/target1";
                    //some handler for this topic
                }
                static class Action2 { .. }
            }
            static class Action3 { .. }
        }
        static class Events { .. }
    }
}
```

as a kind of enumeration that reflects the topic format, which will be "root/commands/someQueue/push", "root/events/status/someOrigin"..

unlike Java you cannot reference the outer class from the inner one, **is there a reflection tecnique to accomplish this?**

I thought about having them extend one another instead of nesting them, but it feels less organized.

I'm not explicitly using "Topic.Commands.path" because i'd like to be able to move them around without changing the code.

Comment: What I strongly suggest is that you rethink this design. C#, Java or not, it is terrible, because of circular dependency. How about you simply make all those classes non-static and pass common dependencies to constructors? Or maybe even stick with static classes (which on its own is not great) but move the common dependecy (`path` in this case) outside. Circular dependencies are hard to reason about, and almost always are a sign of bad design.

Comment: _"unlike Java you cannot reference the outer class from the inner one"_ - can you please elaborate?

Comment: Do you actually mean non-static classes? Because it looks like you want to create instances of those classes, and that is not possible with static classes. You can "reference" the static classes outright, so you can write { public static string path = Topics.path + "/commands"; }. Example: You can assign a value to the static string path's you are creating like { API.Topics.path = "hello"; }, but if you then call "API.Topics.Commands.path", it will return "someRootPath/commands". However, if you call { API.Topics.path }, it will return "hello".

Comment: @GuruStron: Have a look at this sample code: [Accessing an outer class member from an inner class in Java](https://gist.github.com/mustafaozcetin/3d2e64e88b99dafe40ec619483752468)

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin I know about  inner classes in Java. They about **instance** of outer class. The provided code is using static classes which are pretty much callable.

Comment: @GuruStron: Yes,  the situation is the same in C# and Java with static methods and members. It seems the OP is not aware of the distinction. Outer static members can well be called from the inner ones in C#, too.

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin as i said in the post i am aware that i can call the outer static member using its fully qualified name. I was looking for a *relative* reference, so that in the developing phase i do not have to manually propagate the changes through the tree-like topic structure, or risk a refactor.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution would be to just to refer to the outer class by name:

```
static class API
{
    static class Topics
    {
        static string path = "someRootPath";
        static class Commands
        {
            static string path = Topics.path + "/commands";
        }
    }
}
```

That does not necessarily mean that this is a good design overall. Presumably the paths should be associated with some class, so you might want to make this association clearer by declaring the paths on the class that will actually use it.

A possible approach would be to use attributes to associate paths with classes, similar to the way [asp.net routs requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2). But I cannot make any real recommendation since I'm not sure I understand the use case precisely, and I don't have a lot of experience with the topic anyway.